# Python Cookie Cutter - Conditional Code Block?

Tags: python, templates, cookiecutter

Is it possible do some sort of conditional code block depending on the variable(s) set? I am trying to templatize a project which has some yaml configuration files. I would like a section of the yaml configuration to be optional though, but I do not know if there is a way to do this using `cookiecutter`. I do know that `cookiecutter` supports optional files and directories.

Here is an example:

```
{{ cookiecutter.pipeline_name }}:
  models:
    {{ cookiecutter.model_name }}:
      inference:
        instance_type: {{ cookiecutter.instance_type }}
        containers:
          - image:
              name: {{ cookiecutter.image_name }}
              repo: {{ cookiecutter.image_repo }}
              tag: {{ cookiecutter.image_tag }}
            provider: ecr
            data: {{ cookiecutter.model_artifact }}
        async_inference_config:
          s3_output_path: {{ cookiecutter.async_output_path }}
          max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance: {{ cookiecutter.max_invocations }}
```

The `async_inference_config` block should be optional. If the user doesn't fill in the `async_output_path` and the `max_invocations` variables, then the entire block should be removed. If this is not possible, I could create 2 different `cookiecutter` templates. But seems like a waste considering the only difference between these 2 templates would be the `async_inference_config` block.

Comment: You can use a post-generation hook (https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/hooks.html) and get maximum flexibility that way.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really cookiecutter's functionality but rather Jinja2's one.
Take a look at [this part of it's documentation.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if)

So your code should look similar to this one:

```
{{ cookiecutter.pipeline_name }}:
  models:
    {{ cookiecutter.model_name }}:
      inference:
        instance_type: {{ cookiecutter.instance_type }}
        containers:
          - image:
              name: {{ cookiecutter.image_name }}
              repo: {{ cookiecutter.image_repo }}
              tag: {{ cookiecutter.image_tag }}
            provider: ecr
            data: {{ cookiecutter.model_artifact }}
{% if cookiecutter.async_output_path and cookiecutter.max_invocations %}
        async_inference_config:
          s3_output_path: {{ cookiecutter.async_output_path }}
          max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance: {{ cookiecutter.max_invocations }}
{% endif %}
```